# Two if statements in a row arent working

Tags: jquery

i want to create a slider with if statements while using the keyboard, left n right, up and down.

i thought the solution is an if statement, but when i´m clicking n arrow key both of the animations are starting.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var content_left = $('.content').css('left');



function moveLeft() {

   if (content_left = "-100vw") { 
   console.log(content_left);
       $('.content').animate({
            left: "0vw"
        }, 1000);
    }

  if (content_left = "-200vw") { 
    console.log(content_left);
       $('.content').animate({
            left: "-100vw"
        }, 1000);
    }

    };



function moveRight() {


  if (content_left = "0vw") { 
       $('.content').animate({
            left: "-100vw"
        }, 100);
    }

 if (content_left = "-100vw") { 
    console.log(content_left);
       $('.content').animate({
            left: "-200vw"
        }, 100);
    }

    };


$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       moveRight();
       return false;
    }

   if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       moveLeft();
       return false;
    }
    });

 });
```

here is a link to a codepen with this problem:

[CODE PEN](http://codepen.io/davidliebermann/pen/zxdwoz)

(only left and right – but you can see what the problem is)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. Breaking the Codepen link to get around the code requirement isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to typos. `=` vs `==`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (content_left = "-100vw") {
```

You're setting the value here instead of testing it. Use `==` or `===` instead. The same goes for the rest of the `if` statements.

Your also using outdated `content_left` values.

```
  var content_left = $('.content').css('left');
```

^^ This line should be copied to the beginning of both the `moveLeft` and `moveRight` functions.

Comment: thanks a lot, but it still isn´t working.

Comment: I think i spotted another problem; updated.